# Objective-C Closure to use Swift enum

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I've got Swift enum like this:

```
@objc public enum Status: Int {

    case unknown;
    case ok;
    case failed;
}
```

It's properly bridged to Objective-C, and I can use it as, say `StatusUnknown` in Objective-C.

Now I have a function with callback:

```
+ (void)fetch:(void (^_Nonnull)(BOOL success))completion
```

And all I want is to replace `BOOL` with my `Status` enum. How to do that?

Clearly not like this:

```
+ (void)fetch:(void (^_Nonnull)(Status success))completion // Error: Unknown type name
```

I could use `NSInteger` like this:

```
+ (void)fetch:(void (^_Nonnull)(NSInteger success))completion
```

but then it's not really limiting values to Status enum.

So what is the best way to convey enum here?

Note:

- I simplified question, in reality enum is not called status and has many more values.
- Signature of the function has to match previous signature, but with different argument

Comment: I don't know objective-C, but I wrote some Swift code and looked at the generated header file. I saw the enum being converted to a `enum Status : NSInteger;` with a typedef `typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, Status, closed) {
  StatusUnknown = 0,
  StatusOk = 1,
  StatusFailed = 2,
};`, and the method accepting a closure becomes `- (void)f:(void (^ _Nonnull)(enum Status))c;`. Does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be compatible with objective-c enum must be inherited from Int, like

```
@objc public enum Status: Int {
    case unknown
    case ok
    case failed
}
```

make sure generated bridge header file "YOURPROJECT-Swift.h" contains

```
typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, Status, closed) {
  StatusUnknown = 0,
  StatusOk = 1,
  StatusFailed = 2,
};
```

then in your .m file

```
#import "YOURPROJECT-Swift.h"

...

+ (void)fetch:(void (^_Nonnull)(Status success))completion
{
    // do anything needed    
}
```

Clean/Build - all compiled well. Tested with Xcode 11.2.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify in question that it already was. In code though it was. Still getting an error. But what you are saying is that that method should work. Guess I need to dig then into something else...

Comment: Defining the enum in Swift and adding `typedef SWIFT_ENUM(NSInteger, Status, closed)`in a .h file worked for me